# SimpleHttpConnectionManager being used incorrectly w/ Objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I'm trying to save multiple datastore entities with Objectify and keep getting dozens of "SimpleHttpConnectionManager being used incorrectly" warnings.

I'm using the following code to save the entities (I've tried with and without the `.now()` call):

```
ofy().save().entities(entities).now();
```

Additionally, after about the first half dozen warnings I get the following exception:

```
SEVERE: exception occurred while calling backend method
com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiException: remote API call: I/O error
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

If I iterate through `entities` and save each entity individually, I don't get any warnings, but this isn't ideal due to the speed and cost of multiple calls to the datastore.

I'm saving around 2500 entities and have tried breaking `entities` up into multiple lists (under 1000 items), but get the same warnings.

Is this an issue with Objectify or am I missing a step? Should I not be using Objectify at all?

Comment: Sounds like this might be related to a bug in the local development server (dev_appserver) that is used by the google-cloud-intellij plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unrelated to Objectify. Objectify is a thin layer of code that maps your POJOs to the lower level hashmap-like objects that Google's API uses. For the most part, Objectify operations translate 1-to-1 to low level API calls.

If you rewrite your app to perform the same operations using the low level API, you'll see this exact same problem. That stacktrace with the RemoteApiException comes from deep inside Google's `DatastoreService.put()` method.

I presume you are getting this error from the dev server (it would be VERY odd server-side). Google recently rewrote the app engine dev server and unfortunately it tends to produce opaque errors like this when something goes wrong. I would report this to Google as an error - but make sure to give them the full stacktrace. Scroll down to "Create new App Engine issue" on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Answer (score 1):

With the information you provided, there are several things you can have a look in order to solve your issues with Datastore, so let me go over all of them:

- **ID Generation**: which ID allocation policy are you using? Bear in mind that if you are using *autogenerated @IDs*, you have to [pay special attention](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/BasicOperations#saving) when using Asynchronous saves (calls without the `.now()` call), as they do not automatically populate the ID value on the entity instance. So in this case you should better use Synchronous  saves (with the `.now()` call) to avoid possible issues. You can also use your own ID assignation in order to avoid that operations are left pending for completion of async tasks.
- **Local Development**: in the comment to your question you mentioned that the issue could be related to the local development server, so it would be interesting to know if you are indeed using the `dev_appserver`, and in such case, if you are working with the [local Datastore emulator](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server#using_the_local_datastore) too. That brings us to the previous topic, because if you are using the local Datastore emulator and expect to get autogenerated IDs, you need to specify the policy used for such generation.
- **Objectify**: I myself have not worked much with the Objectify third-party library, but an important thing you need to know about it is that [it is not thread-safe](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/BasicOperations#the-objectify-instance), so an Objectify instance should be used from a single thread. Then, you need to confirm that the AppEngine application you are working with is not threadsafe and is not making use of the same Objectify instance from different threads, as that may cause errors. Note that Cloud Platform does not provide support for the Objectify library (being a third-party library), and its use is only held as reference, so if you keep having problems with it, I'd suggest you move to one of the alternatives for [connecting to Datastore from AppEngine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/#connecting_to_datastore_name_short_with_app_engine), which takes us to the last point.
- **Datastore API and Client Library**: these are the two Google-supported alternatives you can use for connecting to Datastore from AppEngine. The **Datastore API** provides the [`commit` handler](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/commit#request-body) to operate over entities. You can use it to insert a list of entities on the same call. Finally, the **[Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library)** for Java provides the [`datastore.add()` method](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#batch_operations) for inserting individual entities or batches of them (although it is only available for Java 8).

So let me summarize to make everything clear: first, confirm if you are running your application locally or in production with AppEngine (and then if you are using the emulator for Datastore or not); then, check your ID generation policies and type of calls (sync or async), and how they fit your environment; finally, if you keep having issues with Objectify, consider having a look at other alternatives that are specifically supported by Google.